# How to implement a slideshow on WP similar to these examples?

Tags: pagination, gallery, slideshow

I'm a big fan of slideshows like these:

*BEST PLACES TO LIVE*
http://money.cnn.com/magazines/moneymag/bplive/2011/snapshots/PL0846355.html

*Best places for the rich and single*
http://money.cnn.com/galleries/2011/moneymag/1108/gallery.best_places_rich_single.moneymag/index.html

Does anyone have a suggestion how to implement something similar on Wordpress?

My intention is to have whole pages load for each slide to increase the pageview count, but this apparently requires a pagination scheme in the URL for each slide.

Is there a plugin or for this?

***Using WP 3.1.3, Thesis Theme***

Answer (score 3):

This is a lot of customization, but can definitely be done. I do not know of a plugin that will do this for you:

Each slideshow is a category. Each slide is a post. Build a custom template for the post, so it displays the navigation and the content exactly how you want it. Design a category archive page that is the list view. Use [wp-paginate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/screenshots/) if you need better pagination control.